# Cannot import com.google.android.maps.MapView

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I wanna import

> com.google.android.maps.MapView

to my project in Android studio, but it prompt an error which is "Cannot resolve symbol 'maps'".

```
class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
{
      ....
 }
```

How to solve it? Thanks

Comment: why don't you use the latest version of google maps?

Comment: @DroidWorm Narendra, what is the latest version of google maps ? Thanks. I am new to android development

Comment: Check out : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Answer (score 0):

change `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+'`
in your `build.gradle` to
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'`
or you could just use: `SupportMapFragment`
here is a good example:
http://www.truiton.com/2013/05/android-supportmapfragment-example/